# Function is not working when passing two parameters

Tags: javascript, function, getelementbyid

I have this function that checks if a text field is empty by its id, it's working fine when passing one parameter, but when passing two for two text fields it doesn't work, although I setup it the same! Is there something wrong with my code?

You can check it live here: https://jsfiddle.net/hrtkLfrv/1/

```
Category: <input type="text" size="15" id="category_add2"> 
Link: <input type="text" size="15" id="link_add2"> 
<input type="submit" value="Check Two IDs"  onclick=CheckTwoID("category_add2", "link_add2")>

function CheckTwoID(txtLink, txtCategory) {
        if (document.getElementById(txtLink).value == "" || document.getElementById(txtCategory).value == "") {
            window.alert("Empty Fields!");
            //Exit!
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you bind to your `onclick`:

Instead of:

```
onclick=CheckTwoID("category_add2", "link_add2")
```

You should rather write:

```
onclick="CheckTwoID('category_add2', 'link_add2')"
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems my issue was with using double quotations rather than single quotation, as while trying to fix the code I tried it with double quotations for all and it didn't work!

Comment: if you use a double quotations inside double quotation attribute you must escape them as such: `onclick="CheckTwoID(\"category_add2\", \"link_add2\")"` - otherwise, how the browser should know where the attribute ends

Answer (score 0):

You need some quotes around the attributes fields.

```
<input type="submit" value="Check Two IDs" onclick="CheckTwoID('category_add2', 'link_add2')">
<!--                                               ^                                        ^ -->
<!--                                                           ^             ^  ^         ^   -->
```

And I suggest to use single ticks for inner parameter